# How many unit files are required for a systemd

Tags: systemd

https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-converting-sysvinit-scripts/ states

> Here’s a fun fact: everything handled by that 184 line shell script is
>   now handled by 27 lines of systemd configuration, spread across two
>   unit files.

I can find the first file at /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target sshd-keygen.service
Wants=sshd-keygen.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What second file is required and where is it located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init script in the article starts `sshd-keygen` before starting `sshd` so the second unit file being referred is probably the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd-keygen.service` file.

Note that, in the systemd case, `sshd-keygen` is not strictly required by `sshd` since it configured with `Wants=sshd-keygen.service` option. Even if `sshd-keygen.service` fails or is not available, `sshd` will still be started by systemd. However, in the init script linked in the article, it is a strict requirement since the script will fail if `sshd-keygen` fails or is not available.

Comment: Thought they were talking about /etc/sysconfig/sshd, but the number of lines didn't match.

Comment: That is the config file for `sshd`. That will exist even for systemd since that is were sshd gets it's config options from. (`EnvironmentFile=` option in the `[Service]` section)

Answer (score 0):

The second file is `sshd-keygen.service`, which is referenced in your snippet it above.

You can use `locate sshd-keygen.service` to find the file on your system. It's likely located at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd-keygen.service`.